# Python: PyCurl set URL exception

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I try to set the url using this code `c.setopt(pycurl.URL, link)`, but I get the following exception

```
File "/home/sultan/Repository/Django/monitor/app/thread/utils.py", line 164, in perform
    self.proxy_request.setopt(pycurl.URL, u'%s' % unicode(link))
TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt
```

What is wrong with my code?

Sultan

Comment: Is the link parameter you are passing in to c.setopt the correct type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that it accepts strings, not unicode objects. Remove the u and unicode().

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that it accepts strings, not unicode objects. Remove the u and unicode().

Ok, but i have this url:
http://www.example.com/Pok%C3%A9mon

Would it work? Nope!

I use the following approach to solve this problem:
url=str(url.encode('utf-8'))

I can be wrong, so please correct me if there's a better way.